# Check if the upload takes too much time and in case notify the user?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, timeout

I'm try do detect PHP script execution timeout when user uploads a lot of file with a slow Internet connection: i should only warn the user about the timeout.

I'm using [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) along with [`connection_status()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php) in my `upload.php` and inside `on_shutdown()` i create a `$timeout` flag to use in `complete.php` to detect timeout.

The **problem is that results are completely wrong**: i've got a timeout fatal error (it's ok), a require fatal error (at function `require($require)`, as if `$require` was empty) and `complete.php` is not shown.

Too bad, i can't figure how where i'm wrong. This is (short version of) `upload.php` script:

```
<?php
   register_shutdown_function('on_shutdown');
   $require = 'complete.php'; // Complete page

   sleep(50); // fake timeout for testing

   // Do stuff, save files, insert into database...

   // This always invoked
   function on_shutdown()
   {
      global $require;

      $timeout = connection_status() == 2;
      require($require);
   }
?>
```

... and this is `complete.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload complete</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if ($timeout) { ?><!-- is timeout? -->
            <p>Upload process took too much time, results are unpredictable.</p>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use `set_time_limit(0)` on just the upload page and let them upload the files? I'm just asking...

Comment: BTW, when you're first declaring the `$require`, you should use `global $require = 'complete.php';` unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

register_shutdown_function('on_shutdown');
 Will run only after the script is executed.

> "Registers a callback to be executed after script execution finishes or exit() is called." - php.net

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying with timeout, you can check the values of maximum execution time and assign it to 0 for long execution, but security wise 0 is not recommented

```
$maxExeTime = ini_get('max_execution_time'); //this will get maxumum excetion time for PHP script in seconds
echo $maxExeTime;
```

and also you can check below global variable also

```
$postMs = ini_get('post_max_size'); //this will get maxumum size of data to be accepted in $_POST
$upMaxFiles = ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); //this will get maxumum allowed file size for file upload
$noFilesUp = ini_get('max_file_uploads'); //this will get number of files to be load on    single request
```